# Is it possible to create and pass an instance of a model object but not save it in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to be able to create a variable that holds an instance of a model object `User` but not save it to the database.  Is this possible?  Right now when I a do the following it saves it to the database:

```
user = User.new
user.name = "John"
user.save
```

I would like to create a `user` variable that holds the previous information but not have to save it in the database. The reason is the function I need to use expects a `User` object and I don't want to save users yet at that point in the code.

Thanks

Comment: So don't `save`--you're the one saving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave said, just don't save the user variable:

```
user = User.new(:name => "John")
```

Now you can still use methods by passing in the user variable, even though it isn't saved to the database:

```
puts "The user's name is: #{user.name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in the session: `session[:user] = user`.

Comment: With the caveat that if you're using cookie sessions, the user can't be big.